# How do I commit my local files to subversion repo when the repo has changed?

Tags: svn

I use tortoise svn. I added a folder and commit it to the subversion repo. Then, my coworker did some stuff, made a mistake, and delete the entire folder and asks me to re submit the working files.

But now, when I click tortoise svn-> commit, it says that the "no files were changed or added". The files in the server repo is no longer as the entire folder is gone.

If I click update, it will remove my local folder and i don't want that. What I want is to recommit whatever I have on my local folder back to the repo. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Most (modern) Decentralized VCS have an **uncommit** feature. Even if it is very powerful, it is indeed sometimes dangerous if used inappropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *revert* the changes that your coworker did.

First, backup the deleted folder. Now update the parent directory of the folder. Then go to the parent folder -> right click on it -> 'Show log' -> find the entry for the changes that your coworker did -> right click on it -> 'Revert changes from this revision'. Check in your working copy that the directory is back.

Now copy changed files (if any) from backup, do not forget to `svn add` new files (if any). Commit *your directory only* (otherwise other changes your coworker did will be also reverted). Now right click on parent folder -> 'Revert' (this will restore back your co-worker's modifications that have nothing to do with the deleted folder).

By the way, it is important to understand what reverting committed changes does: it applies changes from the commit being reverted 'backwards' to your working copy. So the revision/commit does not disappear from the repository.

Comment: Can't. It says that 'path not found'. It looks like it is trying to merge revision ### from the repo into my local folder, ignoring ancestry. I'm not sure if this makes a difference but the repo folder is gone.

Comment: If this happens when you are trying to revert after the update - just move the backed up directory back into place (make sure that .svn folder is deleted if you are using SVN 1.6 format) and add it as @Cubic suggests.

Comment: No. OK. I click on a local folder, click on show logs. I see the changes my coworker makes and mine. I select mine and click revert. Now, when I click show log, I only see up to rev 105 which is my latest one. But, even then, if I try to add files, it says nothing to add. If I try to commit, it says nothing to commit. I am totally new to subversion so pardon the slowness. If I copy the same folder and call it folder_2, i can add, and commit and it will appear in the repo as http://url/folder_2. The original one is http://url/folder and it was deleted by my coworker. Thanks

Comment: No, no! Do not revert your changes! Only his!

Comment: Ya I did. I select the revision # which is the last commit that I've made and so now my local folder is the "latest" that I want to commit to the svn repo

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12122/discussion-between-yko-and-malenkiy-scot)

Comment: Sorry. I miss the chat. I've never used it before. But I did see your message on reverting to the HEAD and then merging the changes. Thanks. I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could copy your local folder somewhere else, update, then move back the folder add it to subversion and commit (and hit your co-worker with a stick)

Comment: haha. I think yours work although I want to learn subversion. There has to be a more elegant solution. It's SCM and so should be able to handle this kinds of stuff easily. I can't hit my coworker with a stick lol. We are learning this together lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "add" the files to the commit (`svn add` if you were using a terminal version of svn). There should be a command somewhere in Tortoise svn to do that.

Comment: it says nothing to add. It's like my local files don't know that it is different than the repo

Answer (score 0):

You can simply commit your change to a new branch.
If you don't want to switch your main dev. to a new branch, simply do:

- Still commit your changes to a new branch (so it is backup!)
- Merge the main branch with your branch.
- Delete everything (just keep the .svn files) and overwrite with your files (from you branch).
- Commit.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your coworker didn't just delete the directory, but moved it or created another directory in some other location, you could use 'svn switch' (or the tortoise equivalent) to re-point your current working copy to the new repository location.  After that you can safely commit again.

Comment: Yes. I think she did delete the directory. That directory is no longer available in the repo although it is available locally.